# What causes a custom path with linearc to have asymmetrical ripple?

Tags: pstricks

The objective is to make the bottom of a bullet has rounded corners. What I don't understand are:

- Why does the ripple only occur on the bottom part but not on the top part even though the bottom one is just a reflection of the top one?
- Why does the ripple occur for a specific value of `linearc`?
- How to fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\bottom{\psparametricplot{0}{2}{-t^2+6|t}\psline(1,2)}



\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.7+0.1}{5}{%
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-5,-6)(7,3)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,linewidth=2pt,linearc=\n pt]
    {
        \bottom
        \reversepath
        \scale{1 -1}
        \bottom
        \closepath
    }
    \rput[tl](-4,2){\tt linearc=\n pt}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the source of the problem. However, here is a fix for it :)

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\bottom{\psparametricplot{0}{2}{-t^2+6|t}\psline(1,2)}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.1+0.1}{50}{%
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-5,-6)(7,3)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,linewidth=2pt,linearc=\n pt]
    {
        \bottom
        \reversepath
        \scale{1 -1}
        \rlineto(0,-0.001)
        \bottom
        \closepath
    }
    \rput[tl](-4,2){\tt linearc=\n pt}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems `linearc` has no effect for `pscustom`.